# Reading BSDF data format

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have been required to write a function that reads the [BSDF data format defined by Zemax](http://www.zemax.com/kb/articles/229/3/BSDF-Data-Interchange-File-Format-Specification/Page3.html)
An example of such file can be found at the following page: [BSDF file example](http://www.zemax.com/kb/articles/229/4/BSDF-Data-Interchange-File-Format-Specification/Page4.html)

I would like to use, if possible, only standard `ifstream` functions.

I have already prepared all the necessary datamembers inside a dedicated class.

I am now trying to write the function that reads the data from the file.

Problems:

- how do I exclude comment lines? as documented, they start with an hash `#` I was going for something like

  ```
  void ReadBSDFFile(myclass &object)
  {
  ifstream infile;

  infile.open(object.BRDFfilename);

  char c;
  infile.get(c);
  while (c == "#") // Problem, apparently I cannot compare in this way. How should I do it?
  {
     getline(infile, line);
     infile.get(c);
  }
  // at this point I would like to go back one character (because I do not want to lose the non-hash character that ended up in *c*)
  infile.seekg(-1, ios_base::cur);

  // Do all the rest

  infile.close();
  }
  ```
- in a similar way, I would like to verify that I am at the correct line later on (e.g. the "AngleOfIncidence" line). Could I do it in this way?

  ```
  string AngleInc;

  infile >> AngleInc;

  if (AngleInc != "AngleOfIncidence")
  {
     //error
  }
  ```

Thanks to anyone who will comment/help. Constructive criticism is welcomed.

Federico

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Joachim Pileborg below, I managed to proceed up to the data blocks part of the file.

Now I have the following problem. When reaching the datablocks, I wrote the following piece of code, but at the second iteration (`i = 1`) i receive the error message for the TIS line.
Could someone help me understand why this does not work?
Thanks

Note: `blocks` is the number on the AngleOfIncidence line, `rows` the one on the ScatterAzimuth line and `columns` the one on the ScatterRadial. I tested and verified that this part of the function works as desired.

```
// now reading the data blocks.

for (int i=0; i<blocks; i++)
{
    // TIS line
    getline(infile, line);
    if (line.find("TIS") == string::npos)
    {
        // if not, error message
    }

    // Data block
    for (int j=0; j<rows; j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<columns; k++)
        {
            infile >> object.BRDFData[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

solved adding `infile.seekg(+2, ios_base::cur);` as a last line of the `i` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading loop could be simplified like this:

```
std::string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    if (line[0] != '#')
    {
        // Not a comment, do something with the line
        if (line.find("AngleOfIncidence") != std::string::npos)
        {
            // On the AngleOfIncidence line, do special things here
        }
    }
}
```

It's might not be optimal, just something written at the top of my head, but should work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I need to adapt it a bit( a `while (getline(infile, line))` loop does not quite solve my problems), but I guess that it's a pretty fine starting point.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the format you provided:

> Any line that starts with the # symbol is ignored as a comment line.

So what you need to do is the following

```
Read the file line by line
If the line starts with # ignore it
Otherwise process the line.
```

The `while` you have used is wrong. Use the [`getLine`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) function instead and compare its first character with the `#`.